# How to create custom Ubuntu install with packages, system settings, defaults?

Tags: boot, system-installation

Is there  a way to create a custom Ubuntu install that will have packages installed, with pre-set system settings and defaults to? It would also be nice to have folders pre-made and already available that I placed there.

I am working on a team project where Ubuntu is used for system development.  I want it so that they can install Ubuntu like they would through USB normally but to have it so that they have  exactly what is needed.

I know there is a way to do a custom Ubuntu install with selected packages but I guess I am asking for a solution almost akin to a system image flash. Problem is, we don't use the same laptops so I don't want whatever Ubuntu loads for  me to load  for them as drivers  or else it  may wreck stuff.

Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to customize the Ubuntu Live CD?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/48535/how-to-customize-the-ubuntu-live-cd)

Comment: Use the second method (Rinzwind's answer).

Answer (score 0):

use the ubuntu preseed for that.

In ubuntu iso you can find it under preseed/ubuntu.seed

[reference link](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/installation-guide/i386/apb.html)